# Vertical spacing in Sublime Text quick improve readability (editing script PHP or any other programming language)

Tags: php, sublimetext

I always  use sublime text to edit FILes: php and htm.  Sometimes the font looks so small in my vision. I wonder if somewhere around the world, another persons happens the same way.

To  improve readability, is there somewhere we can use some kind of vertical spacing just as in MS Word because I usually adjust vertical spacing in M$ Word to improve readability.

The text can still be able to read fast. We can quickly differentiate between punctuation and the actual words, so we can code php with comfort.

Comment: Thanks in Advance if you have suggestion or a better way. I'm sure we can face and solve these problems alltogether :)

Comment: Have you tried to google `sublimetext font size` or `sublimetext vertical space`?

Answer (score 2):

The settings you are looking for:

`"line_padding_bottom": 1,
"line_padding_top": 1,`

See the [Fonts and Spacing](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/simple-visual-enhancements-for-better-coding-in-sublime-text--webdesign-18052) section for details.

Comment: after trying and searching for the best visual enchancement, we can add this lines "line_padding_top": 1,
"line_padding_bottom": 0,   and also can change font and size:  
“font_face”: “Inconsolata";
"font_size": 18;

Answer (score 0):

Font can be changed using:

`"font_face": "Courier New",
 "font_size": 10`

This is from the sublime 3 [doc](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/font.html)

Comment: thanks guys, for your answer. many many thanksto all of you.
we can use cursor_Prompt  to improve  READAbility ::  
{
// cursor_Prompt  to improve  READAbility ::  
    "caret_extra_width": 2,
    "wide_caret": true,

 "update_check": "false"
}

//complete  READ improve   I usually use  in my sublemetext:
//change fontcurly. element naturally like a grass.
// i hope you can feelit too. the eyes wont  tired so quickly 
{
 "font_face": "Lucida Handwriting",
 "font_size": 9,
 "save_on_focus_lost": "true",
 "tab_size": 2,
 "word_wrap": "false",
}